# How to Implement a search function in reactJS using MaterialUI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, searchbar

I try to develop a pokedex using the pokeapi. For now it works fine, the pokemon are fetched correctly and are displayed in a container. Now i want to implement a function to search and filter the pokemon. Therefore i used MaterialUI to put a searchBar on top of the App.

The fetched pokemon are given from App.js to my Component PokemonList which maps the data. My idea is now to filter the pokemonData before it is given to PokemonList to map only the pokemon i am looking for. But here i am stuck. I have no idea how to connect the search function with my pokemonData Hook from App.js . Can you help me?

This is my searchBar Component:

```
const SearchAppBar = () => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    console.log(search)
    return (
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <AppBar position="static" sx={{ bgcolor: "black"}}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              sx={{ mr: 2 }}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              noWrap
              component="div"
              sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
            >
              
              <img src={logo} alt="logo" width="150" height="auto" />
            </Typography>
            <Search>
              <SearchIconWrapper>
                <SearchIcon />
              </SearchIconWrapper>
              <StyledInputBase 
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                id = 'searchbox' 
                placeholder="Search for Pokémon..."
                inputProps={{'aria-label': 'search'}}
              />
            </Search>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Box>
    );
  }


export default SearchAppBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should save the entered value from input into a state and filter your data based on that state

Comment: Okay, i have updated it, added a hook to save the input (see above). How can i use the Hook search now in App.js?

Comment: i didn’t understand where your pokemonData is. 
if it's inside another component you should pass the input out and get it with props
your SearchAppBar component should get 2 props : value and onChange 
then you pass those 2 to your inputs
then where you are using the SearchAppBar you should define a new state and save the input value there and then filter it with your data

Comment: App.js (pokemonData fetched from API and stored in state pokemonData). Here i call the pokemonList.js and give the PokemonData in form of a prop. Here the given Data is mapped and rendered. SearchAppBar is a third component...

Comment: treat SearchAppBar as a ui component like a input
it should accept value and onChange props

Comment: Now i get this error: Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`SearchAppBar`).